# How can I perform a forward selection, backward selection, and stepwise regression in R?

Tags: r, regression

I am trying to perform forward, backward, and stepwise regression on some data; however, the summaries look fairly similar for all of them, so I was wondering if I did everything right?

Forward Selection

```
#Forward Selection
regA <-  step(lm(Rut ~ Visc + Surface + Run + Voids + Visc*Run 
                  + Surface*Run + Voids*Run,data=dat),
               direction="forward")
regA
summary(regA)
```

Backwards Elimination

```
lmB <- step(lm(Rut ~ Visc + Surface + Run + Voids + Visc*Run 
        + Surface*Run + Voids*Run,data=dat),direction="backward")
lmB
summary(lmB)
```

Stepwise

```
reg1C <-  lm(Rut ~ Visc + Surface + Run + Voids + Visc*Run 
                  + Surface*Run + Voids*Run,data=dat)
step(reg1C)
summary(reg1C)
```

Comment: Could you include the summaries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you are trying to perform a regression to predict the price of a house. Let's say some of our variables are the amount bedrooms, bathrooms, size of the house, date listed, and year built. See below for the forward, backwards, and stepwise automated selection techniques using R.

```
#Forward
nullmod <- lm(Price ~ 1, data = dat)
fullmod <- lm(Price ~ Beds + Baths + size + Date + Year 
             + AshburnMetro,data=dat)
reg1A <- step(nullmod, scope = list(lower = nullmod, upper = fullmod),
              direction="forward")

reg1A
str(summary(reg1A))

#Backwards
fullmod <- lm(Price ~ 1, data = dat)
nullmod <- lm(Price ~ Beds + Baths + size + Date + Year 
              + AshburnMetro,data=dat)
reg1B <- step(nullmod, scope = list(lower = fullmod, upper = nullmod),
              direction="backward")

reg1B
str(summary(reg1B))
summary(reg1B)

#Stepwise
fullmod <- lm(Price ~ 1, data = dat)
nullmod <- lm(Price ~ Beds + Baths + size + Date + Year 
             + AshburnMetro,data=dat)
reg1C <- step(nullmod, scope = list(lower = fullmod, upper = nullmod),
              direction="both")

reg1C
str(summary(reg1C))
```

Answer (score 0):

***StepReg*** R package can do this. For example,

```
library(StepReg)
formula <- mpg ~ .

# forward with 'AIC'
stepwise(formula=formula,
         data=mtcars,
         include=NULL,
         selection="forward",
         select="AIC")

# backward with 'SBC'
stepwise(formula=formula,
         data=mtcars,
         include=NULL,
         selection="backward",
         select="SBC")

# stepwise with 'SL'
stepwise(formula=formula,
         data=mtcars,
         include=NULL,
         selection="bidirection",
         select="SL",
         sle=0.15,
         sls=0.15)
```